# Change ExtendedTemplate field that is being passed to app in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where do I change this element?  It says mmcs: but I need it to say afghan:
I'm trying to change it so that it propagates as the EventLabel through the application.  I've been trying to change it in the .aspx documents but it must be coming from a control file somewhere as it appears to have to affect when I recompile the application.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking for, but it sounds like it's possible that you may want to check the `<pages><controls>` section of your web.config file...  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164640.aspx for more info.